# Perform refresh on a JQuery to refresh select picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have the below HTML code, which can select multiple options with live options. I am very new to jquery, and I wrote a code to refresh if multiple options are selected

```
    <div class="col-sm">
        <select id="dataPicker" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow rule-options" multiple title="Rule Description" data-live-search="true" data-width="140px" data-size="5">
            <option data-tokens="A"> A thru Column G </option>
            <option data-tokens="B">B toC</option>
            <option data-tokens="G">G to A</option>
       </select>
    </div>

<div class="container">
            <div class = "row">

                <div class="ml-auto p-1">
                  <button class="btn btn-dark " type="Validate">Run Validation</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-dark" id="myButton" type="Clear" >Clear Validation</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
        $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
            $("#dataPicker").selectpicker("refresh");
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: to help you, you really need to add more to your question. can you at least include relevant bits of your HTML?

Comment: Hi, I have just updated it. Included more details to the code along with the HTML and jquery

Comment: where is your button in your html? and what exactly do you want to do? unselect the selected options?

Comment: Hi, I have included the button too. Yes exactly un-select the select options

Comment: Are you trying to reset select value to default?

Comment: Hi @Raj, please check my answer when you have a moment

Answer (score 0):

A simple and working solution is:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#dataPicker').find('option').prop("selected", false);
})
```

You can test it on JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8e5agdpq/

I also read that there are many compatibility issues among jQuery versions.
A brutal, non elegant and general solution that worked in all my tests is also:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#dataPicker')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option data-tokens="A"> A thru Column G </option>')
        .append('<option data-tokens="B">B toC</option>')
        .append('<option data-tokens="G">G to A</option>')
    ;
})
```

You can test it in JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/koxs785a/